# DISKWarn Running out of space

Tags: disk-space-utilization

I have a dedicated server and for the past few days i am getting these email notifications about the file system running out of space. I am looking for the best and easiest way to fix this. Any suggestions are appreciated.  This is the message I am getting:

> DISKWARN: / on server.xxxxxxx.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx): 39.25/49.22 GB - 85%

The file system /dev/mapper/vg_server1-lv_root, which is mounted at /, has reached warn status because it is 85% full

> Notification Type:    diskwarn
>
> Filesystem:   /dev/mapper/vg_server1-lv_root
>
> Mount Point:  /
>
> Percentage Full:   85%
>
> Disk Information:
>
> Used: 39.54GB
>
> Available: 7.17GB
>
> Total: 49.22GB
>
> ChkServd Version: 15.3

Comment: … are you trolling?

Comment: what is that suppose to mean. i am new with dedicated servers and i am not sure what that error means, I want to make sure i don't delete any important files and crash the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is getting full.

Either delete some stuff, or upgrade to a bigger drive.

Comment: I have multiple cpanel accounts on this dedicated server. I also have serveral backups generated for these accounts. So you think if i delete these backup archive files, it'll help.  My server was suppose to have 1TB of space but that DISK Warn message says 39/49GB so thats where i am not sure what space it wants free.

Comment: @HarrisonSamuel Yeah, you need to get some help from someone who knows what he's doing, honestly. I'm a Windows guys and I ostensibly know more about Linux filesystems than you do.  One of the partitions on your disk is filling up.  So you need to free up space **on that partition** or expand it.

Comment: Thanks, thats why i posted this question here and see if i can get some advice on how to get this fixed.

Comment: @HarrisonSamuel When Hopeless said "get some help", I believe he meant more PAY someone to help.  The level of support you appear to need goes well beyond what we are able to (or willing to) provide for free here.  So much so that you may want to consider managed hosting rather than a dedicated server.  Dedicated servers are great for experienced linux admins.  Not so much for the inexperienced.

Comment: ok thankyou all for your suggestions